# Groupby Issue with putting spaces in the string stored

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Hey I'm trying to do a Group by for this. I've used `df.groupby('COLUMN_NAME').sum()`
And it comes out as a string with no spaces in between. How do I add spaces? Finding some form of trouble.

I've tried `df['COLUMN_NAME_WITH_INFO_THAT_HAS_STRING_WITH_NO_SPACE'] = df['COLUMN_NAME_WITH_INFO_THAT_HAS_STRING_WITH_NO_SPACE'] + ''`

But no luck. I'm at the 3rd Part of the image, I can't show code as it may have some vital information but I'm kinda stuck here :/

Basically, till the sum part, I've reached. Just don't know how to add spaces.

[image: Road Map of what I want]

[image: Spaces Needed/required]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
ow=new.groupby('Del_Number').agg(' '.join)
```

OR

For particular column:

```
ow=new.groupby('Del_Number')['Article_Code'].agg(' '.join)
#OR
ow=new.groupby('Del_Number').agg({'Article_Code':' '.join})
```